# how do I import a CPAN module using XS into my project?

Tags: perl, cpan

My company has policies against using Perl modules which are not in Debian/Ubuntu's repositories. To "import" a non-xs module into my project/repo, it's usually just a matter of copying over the .pm files and putting them in the appropriate directory in lib/. Then I can `use` as if I'd cpan installed it.

But what do I do for an XS module? How do I "pre-compile" and to where should I copy over the .so and other XS related files? If you look, for example, at Ubuntu's DBD-SQLite package contents [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/libdbd-sqlite3-perl/filelist), it seems like it should definitely be possible.

Comment: If you're willing to circumvent the company's policy by installing the module by hand, why not just use the `cpan` utility? Modules with an XS component need to be built against your perl's configuration, and cpan is the easiest way to get it right

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [dh-make-perl](http://search.cpan.org/~dam/DhMakePerl-0.72/dh-make-perl) for making `.deb` packages of your perl modules. That way you can install them like a regular shipped module.

You should also read [Building Debian packages of Perl modules](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/78/Building_Debian_packages_of_Perl_modules)